# IntegrityError, (1048, "Column 'category_owner_id' cannot be null") in Django REST with axios

Tags: django, reactjs, post, django-rest-framework, axios

I would like to POST server's data to frontend by axios,
But I continuously face the error:

> IntegrityError at /profile/
>   (1048, "Column 'category_owner_id' cannot be null")

I'm using DRF in backend and React in frontend. Here is my React and DRF part.

**getCategory.js**

```
axios({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { 
            data: this.state.information,
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
     })
     .then(res => {
         console.log(res);
     })
     .catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
     })
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'category_name', 'category_owner_id', 'parentId')
```

**views.py**

```
class SettingView(viewsets.ModelViewSet) :
    queryset = models.Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer

    def get(self, request) :
        return JsonResponse(context)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("ok")
```

Of course, I quickly checked to go inside `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/`

If there is null value in column `category_owner_id`, but none of them is null..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYYFm.png)

I'm new to django REST Framework, so all of your help will be great for me!

Comment: The exception says that, you are not passing `category_owner_id` from the react app to DRF

Comment: @JPG Thanks for reply, you mean that If I want to get 'category_owner_id' value by HTTP, I have to post the same value at first?

Comment: Nop. You are sending some data to Django API while making your `HTTP POST` request. In that data, the `category_owner_id` is not included

Comment: @JPG then, Do I put `category_owner_id` value in `data` (the parameter of axios)?

Comment: I'm not sure about the react side. But you should try something like that

Comment: @JPG I add it like `data : { profileData : this.state.information, category_owner_id: 1 }` but the error still be.. :(

Comment: Is catergory_owner a ForeignKey can you post your models.py here?

Answer (score 1):

Use ModelSerializer instead of HyperlinkedModelSerializer it might help

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'category_name', 'category_owner_id', 'parentId')
```

Also if you have depth set to 1 it causes same issues, you can remove and try

```
# depth = 1
```